# Appendix Footer Numbering

Tags: numbering, appendices

I am new to LaTex and I was told to ask only one question at a time, so please have patience with me.  If you see similar postings, remember each has a different question.
In the appendix page footer, how do I make it number subsequent appendices as B, C, D etc.?
Here is the functioning file:

```
\documentclass[pdftex]{article}
\title{ENVE Template}

%PACKAGES
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{longtable}
    \setlength\LTleft{0pt}
    \setlength\LTright{0pt}
\usepackage{color,soul}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage[table[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{pdflscape}


%COMMANDS
\newcommand{\version}{4.0} %%%%%%UPDATE VERSION NUMBER HERE
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\renewcommand*{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\hlgreen}[1]{{\sethlcolor{enve-green}\hl{#1}}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\hlgray}[1]{{\sethlcolor{gray}\hl{#1}}}
\newcommand\textbox[1]{%
    \parbox{0.33/textwidth}{#1}%
}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
%
\definecolor{enve-green}{RGB}{123,135,56}
\definecolor{gray}{RGB}{83,86,90}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\sectionfont{\color{enve-green}}

%MARGINS
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1.5in, left=1in, right=1in]{geometry}
\setlength{\headheight}{40pt}

%HEADER & FOOTER
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}% for vertical centering text in X column
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\flushright\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}c}
\newcolumntype{W}{>{\flushleft\arraybackslash}X} % my attempt to align tabularx environment

\fancypagestyle{firstpagestyle}{%HEADER/FOOTER FOR COVER PAGE ONLY
    \chead{\small JOE'S TEST FILE}
    \cfoot{\small JOE'S TEST FILE}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}   
\pagestyle{fancy} %HEADER/FOOTER FOR REST OF DOC
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \fancyhead{}    
    \chead{
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
        \begin{tabular}[c]{|c|c|c|}
        \hline 
        {\cellcolor{gray}\small\color{white}\textbf{JOES'S TEST FILE}} & {\small\textbf{JOE'S TEST FILE}} & {\cellcolor{enve-green}\small\color{white}\textbf{SHORT TITLE}} \\
        \hline
        \end{tabular}}

 %%% TO BE REPLACED BY IMAGE OF LOGO

    \fancyfoot[C]{\small JOE'S TEST FILE 
    \\ \thepage}
\fancypagestyle{plain}


%LEFTBAR SPECIFICATIONS
\renewenvironment{leftbar}[2][\hsize]
{
    \def\FrameCommand
    {
        {\color{enve-green}\vrule width 3pt}
        \hspace{0pt}
    }
    \MakeFramed{\hsize#1\advance\hsize-\width\FrameRestore}
}
{\endMakeFramed}

\begin{document} 








%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% VERSION HISTORY 
\pagenumbering{roman}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\center\section*{Version History}\label{history}

\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor{enve-green}\color{white}\textbf{Date}} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor{enve-green}\color{white}\textbf{Version}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor{enve-green}\color{white}\textbf  {Affected Sections}} \\ \hline

    M/D/YYYY & 1.0 & All Sections \\ \hline

\end{tabular}

\clearpage
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% TABLE OF CONTENTS



\begingroup
\makeatletter
\let\ps@fancy\ps@empty
\tableofcontents\label{toc}
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\clearpage
\endgroup

\pagestyle{fancy} %HEADER/FOOTER FOR REST OF DOC
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \chead{
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
        \begin{tabular}[c]{|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        {\cellcolor{gray}\small\color{white}\textbf{TEST FILE}} & {\small\textbf{JOE'S TEST FILE}} & {\cellcolor{enve-green}\small\color{white}\textbf{SHORT TITLE}} \\
        \hline 
        \end{tabular}}

\clearpage


\appendix
\setcounter{page}{1}
\renewcommand{\thepage}{A-\arabic{page}}
\section*{Appendix}\label{appendix}

\clearpage

\begin{landscape}
\begin{sidewaysfigure}
\appendix
\setcounter{page}{1}
\renewcommand{\thepage}{B-\arabic{page}}

\section*{This Should be In Portrait}
\subsection{First Subsection}
Test text

\end{sidewaysfigure}

\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Replace `A`  with `\thechapter`.

Comment: Hello John, I do not understand you suggestion. When I replace A with \thechapter, LaTex returns several error messages labeled: "undefined control sequence"

Comment: Oops, no chapter in article class.  Also, \section* does not increment \thesection.  Will work on it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your appendices to show up in the table of contents, you need to use `\section` instead of `\section*`.

Also, I tried to use `\counterwithin{page}{section}`, but while most counters start at 0, page starts at 1, and I assume page `A-0` is not desired.

BTW, using pdflscape **instead** of rotating or sidewaysfigure causes landscape pages to appear right side up (except for the footer and header).

```
\documentclass[pdftex]{article}
\title{ENVE Template}

%PACKAGES
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{longtable}
    \setlength\LTleft{0pt}
    \setlength\LTright{0pt}
\usepackage{color,soul}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage[table[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdflscape}


%COMMANDS
\newcommand{\version}{4.0} %%%%%%UPDATE VERSION NUMBER HERE
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\renewcommand*{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\hlgreen}[1]{{\sethlcolor{enve-green}\hl{#1}}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\hlgray}[1]{{\sethlcolor{gray}\hl{#1}}}
\newcommand\textbox[1]{%
    \parbox{0.33/textwidth}{#1}%
}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
%
\definecolor{enve-green}{RGB}{123,135,56}
\definecolor{gray}{RGB}{83,86,90}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\sectionfont{\color{enve-green}}

%MARGINS
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1.5in, left=1in, right=1in]{geometry}
\setlength{\headheight}{40pt}

%HEADER & FOOTER
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}% for vertical centering text in X column
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\flushright\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}c}
\newcolumntype{W}{>{\flushleft\arraybackslash}X} % my attempt to align tabularx environment

\fancypagestyle{firstpagestyle}{%HEADER/FOOTER FOR COVER PAGE ONLY
    \chead{\small JOE'S TEST FILE}
    \cfoot{\small JOE'S TEST FILE}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}   
\pagestyle{fancy} %HEADER/FOOTER FOR REST OF DOC
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \fancyhead{}    
    \chead{
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
        \begin{tabular}[c]{|c|c|c|}
        \hline 
        {\cellcolor{gray}\small\color{white}\textbf{JOES'S TEST FILE}} & {\small\textbf{JOE'S TEST FILE}} & {\cellcolor{enve-green}\small\color{white}\textbf{SHORT TITLE}} \\
        \hline
        \end{tabular}}

 %%% TO BE REPLACED BY IMAGE OF LOGO

    \fancyfoot[C]{\small JOE'S TEST FILE 
    \\ \thepage}
\fancypagestyle{plain}


%LEFTBAR SPECIFICATIONS
\renewenvironment{leftbar}[2][\hsize]
{
    \def\FrameCommand
    {
        {\color{enve-green}\vrule width 3pt}
        \hspace{0pt}
    }
    \MakeFramed{\hsize#1\advance\hsize-\width\FrameRestore}
}
{\endMakeFramed}

\begin{document} 








%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% VERSION HISTORY 
\pagenumbering{roman}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\center\section*{Version History}\label{history}

\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor{enve-green}\color{white}\textbf{Date}} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor{enve-green}\color{white}\textbf{Version}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor{enve-green}\color{white}\textbf  {Affected Sections}} \\ \hline

    M/D/YYYY & 1.0 & All Sections \\ \hline

\end{tabular}

\clearpage
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% TABLE OF CONTENTS



\begingroup
\makeatletter
\let\ps@fancy\ps@empty
\tableofcontents\label{toc}
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\clearpage
\endgroup

\pagestyle{fancy} %HEADER/FOOTER FOR REST OF DOC
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \chead{
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
        \begin{tabular}[c]{|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        {\cellcolor{gray}\small\color{white}\textbf{TEST FILE}} & {\small\textbf{JOE'S TEST FILE}} & {\cellcolor{enve-green}\small\color{white}\textbf{SHORT TITLE}} \\
        \hline 
        \end{tabular}}

\clearpage


\appendix
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\thesection-\arabic{page}}
\section{Appendix}\label{appendix}
\setcounter{page}{1}

%\clearpage% redundant

\begin{landscape}

\section{This Should be In Portrait}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\subsection{First Subsection}
Test text

\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```